# Command for horizontally flipped newline symbol

Tags: symbols, arrows

I'm looking for the command to produce the often used symbol indicating a line break --- but flipped horizontally.
So basically this symbol:

```
|
|
|    \
|------
     /
```

It should fit within one line and should not require using a figure or floating object.

Thanks in advance.

*Edit*: An example of a symbol, which satisfies my needs is the `\Lsh` arrow --- but rotated by 180°.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create it whit the Tikz package.
With this code you define the symbol:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\pagestyle{empty}  
\begin{document}  
\tikz{\draw[-latex] (0,0.2) |- (0.2,0);}  
\end{document}
```

With pdfcrop (that you have on your machine if you're using TeXLive or MacTeX) you can trim the symbol from the page. Just write in a console (or terminal or command prompt)

```
pdfcrop <path of file>/filename.pdf
```

and it will create a cropped pdf with only the symbol inside. After that you can use it as an image on your document

```
bla bla \includegraphics{symbol.pdf} bla bla
```

You could define a macro to speed up the symbol writing if you have to use it lots of times

Comment: That looks (almost) nice. Thank you a lot. One follow up question: How do I get the arrow non-filled? Like the arrow of `\rightarrow` ?

Comment: just change the option `-latex` with `->` at the `\draw` command and you'll get exactly the same arrow tip.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This definitely looks exactly as I imagined. Guess, I will use Tikz more often in the future.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\Huge
$\Rsh$ $\Lsh$ $\drsh$ $\dlsh$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\Rsh$}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kind of. I'm just not satisfied with that hook at all. I'm looking for more the kind of `\Lsh` but rotated by 180°.

Comment: @T. K. see my updated answer